# Selenium SSL Handshake Problem

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

While attempting to access a test portal, I'm encountering the following problem while using the `selenium.start("captureNetworkTraffic=true");` mode.

HTTP ERROR: 400

```
Could not proxy https://myurl.com
java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't establish SSL handshake.  Try using trustAllSSLCertificates.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

RequestURI=/auth/login
```

Note that this happens only in the captureNetworkTrafficMode. A simple `selenium.start();` works with no problem at all.

Here's the access code -

```
RemoteControlConfiguration settings = new RemoteControlConfiguration();
File f = new File("C:\\selenium-profile");
BrowserConfigurationOptions bco = new BrowserConfigurationOptions();
bco.setCommandLineFlags("-trustAllSSLCertificates");
bco.setCommandLineFlags("-disable-web-security");
bco.setCommandLineFlags("-avoidProxy");
settings.setFirefoxProfileTemplate(f);
settings.setReuseBrowserSessions(true);
settings.setSingleWindow(true);
SeleniumServer seleniumserver=new SeleniumServer(settings);
seleniumserver.boot();
seleniumserver.start();
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"*chrome","http://myurl.com") {
        public void open(String url) {
        commandProcessor.doCommand("open", new String[] {url,"true"});
                }
            };
selenium.start("captureNetworkTraffic=true");
selenium.open("/");
```

This problem seems to have been beaten to death, but I still haven't come across a convincing solution...Most recommend the creation of a custom FF profile, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It boiled down to an additional browser setting to trust all SSL certificates:

```
settings.setTrustAllSSLCertificates(true);
```

Comment: I am getting same problem in php. I dont know is there any RemoteControlConfiguration class in php. Please help if you have any idea :)